# Using std::accumulate to find sum of array

Tags: c++

Here's my array:

```
std::array<int, 4> mark;
```

Here's a function I have:

```
float getAverage() {
        float sum = 0;
        sum = std::accumulate(mark, mark + mark.size(), 0);
        return sum /= mark.size();
    }
```

But I get following error:

```
Invalid operands to binary expression ('std::array<int, markAmount>' and 'std::__1::array::size_type' (aka 'unsigned long'))
```

Which is understandable, as `mark` and `mark.size()` have different types, but I don't understand how to make it in other way. Should I cast their types? But why it's not made automatically?
Is `array` similar to `&array[0]`? As this is what I need for `std::accumulate`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike the built-in C-style arrays, `std::array` does not automatically decay to a pointer to its first element. Use `std::begin` and `std::end` to get the iterators (raw pointers in this case):

```
std::accumulate(std::begin(mark), std::end(mark), 0);
```

or member functions `.begin()` and `.end()`.

Answer (score 0):

`std::accumulate(mark.begin(), mark.end(), 0);`

You need to provide iterators to begin and end point.

Answer (score 0):

`std::array` is not a c-array, ie it does not decay to a pointer. Thats one reason to use it. `std::array` has no `operator+(size_t)` and thats what the error is trying to tell you. If you want to accumulate from begin till end then use `begin()` and `end()`.